# how to remove warring in opencart most view page?

Tags: php, opencart

how to remove warring in opencart most view page?

everything work fine only show this below notice please help me how to remove.

http://www.a1dealshop.com/about-us

> Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49
>   Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49
>   Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49
>   Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49
>   Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49
>   Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49
>   Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49
>   Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49
>   Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49
>   Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49Notice: Undefined index: stock_status in /home/adealsho/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_mostview.php on line 49

Comment: check if the index "stock_status" exists in the given var with isset() before accessing it

Comment: no initialization with $stock_status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `isset()` checks to see if the variable is set and not null.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php. Since it is in your controller file it should look something like this:

`if (isset($this->request->post['stock_status'])) {
                        $this->data['stock_status'] = $this->request->post['stock_status'];
                    }  else {
                        $this->data['stock_status'] = '';
                    }` (your basically sending it to view).

Note: It is hard to say because I am not looking at your code, also if your are going to be messing with code avoid core files and change files in VQmod->VQcache.